# Understand "find maximum occuring char" in a string algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, kotlin, ascii

I'm learning Data Structures and Algorithms and I've a small problem of understanding the process of find which char occurs the most in a string.

I understand the general goal - having an array that represent the count of a specific char, I obviously understand how to find max in array but I've big problem with this chuck of code(code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/return-maximum-occurring-character-in-the-input-string/):

```
        int count[] = new int[256]; 

          for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) 
            count[str.charAt(i)]++; <-- what I don't understand
```

I'm initializing count array to hold ints, but inside the for loop I'm searhing for specific char in a string, so for example:

```
count["t"]++
```

So it basically telling me "give me the value of index "t"?  how can I even search with chararter where I should search with index?

Also in kotlin I'm getting expection (`count[str.get(i)]`) that it's expecting int, not char.

I probably missed fundamental concept that prevent me from understand this, but after short google search I didn't find  much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java will convert the `char` into an `int`, for instance, 'A' to `65` according to the `ASCII` table.

[image]

As long as your `string` does not contain a character that would return a value bigger than `255` (*e.g.,* `"€"`), an array of `256` positions will be enough to map the possible `chars` into array positions. For instance, for the English alphabet, it would be enough. Nevertheless, since the char in Java is `2 bytes` (16 bits), an array of size `65536` (2^16) is enough to be on *the safe side*.
You can also calculate the `max` `int` value from all the chars present on that string (assuming a non-null or empty string) and allocate the array accordingly:

```
int count[] = new int[str.chars().max().orElse(0)+1];
```

Returning to your question:

```
count[some_char]++
```

Converts `some_char` into an `int`, and increments by one value on the corresponding array `count` position.

You can think about this process as a simple hash function that maps 'char' to 'int', and even though it is simple, it perfectly suits the problem at hand since it uniquely maps a given char to a position on that array.

> I'm initializing count array to hold ints, but inside the for loop I'm
> searhing for specific char in a string, so for example:
>
> count["t"]++
> So it basically telling me "give me the value of index
> "t"? how can I even search with chararter where I should search with
> index?

Be aware that `count["t"]++` would give you a compile error, the function `str.charAt(i)` returns you a `char`, not a `String`, hence 't' and not "t".

A running example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FindMaximumOccurringChar {

    private static int[] countChar(String str) {
        int[] count = new int[str.chars().max().orElse(0) + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i< str.length(); i++)
            count[str.charAt(i)]++;
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "miaumiauuuuu";
        int[] count = countChar(str);
        String str_without_duplicated_char = Arrays.stream(str.split(""))
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.joining());

        for (int i=0; i<str_without_duplicated_char.length(); i++){
            System.out.println("The char '"+str_without_duplicated_char.charAt(i)+"' shows up "
                    + count[str_without_duplicated_char.charAt(i)] +" times");
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
The char 'm' shows up 2 times
The char 'i' shows up 2 times
The char 'a' shows up 2 times
The char 'u' shows up 6 times
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, `count[str.charAt(i)]++` , storing the count of each character of your input string. Java converts each char index into ASCII value.

```
let say str = "abca";

For each iteration : 
count['a'] = 1; or count[97] = 1;  a has ascii value 97
count['b'] = 1; or count[98] = 1;  b has ascii value 98
count['c'] = 1; or count[99] = 1;  c has ascii value 99
count['a'] = 2; or count[97] = 2;
```